# How to fill a [u8] array with a repeated u16 value?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, type-punning, rust-no-std

I am looking to build an array that will be copied into RAM and sent to an LCD driver. I would like to be able to pass in a color value (`color: u16`) and use it to populate the array. Note that I am using `#![no_std]` as this is intended for an embedded application.

The obvious simple approach would be as follows:

```
let mut block: [u8;256] = [0; 256];
for i in (0..block.len()).step_by(2) {
    block[i] = ((color && 0xFF00) >> 8) as u8;
    block[i+1] = (color && 0xFF) as u8;
}
```

As more of my personal experience comes from C, I wondered if there were any *better* solutions using type casting and conversion. For example, using Rust to initialize a u16 array and cast as a u8 array:

```
let block_u16: [u16; 128] = [color; 128]
let block_u8 = block_u16 as [u8; 256];
```

For reference, the target function prototype is:

```
spi::setup_block(block: &[u8]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could go the unsafe route via [transmute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html), but I would not recommend it. I would not vouch for a C-style version to do the same on a little and big-endian machine.

Personally I would take the chunk iterator over the slice.

```rust
let color_bytes = color.to_le_bytes();
for word in block.chunks_exact_mut(2) {
    word[0] = color_bytes[0];
    word[1] = color_bytes[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was such a thing. I'll definitely bring this in.

Comment: I will use the transmute method and fall back to the for loop if needed. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like your second approach (casting the `u16` array to a `u8` pointer).

```
let color: u16 = 0x0102;
let mut block: [ u16; 128 ] = [ color; 128 ];
let mut block = unsafe { 
    core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut( block.as_mut_ptr( ) as *mut u8, block.len( ) * 2 ) 
};
```

Beware of `endianness` with this solution, it might not do what you want on your target architecture.

Comment: I will try using this and post results. Thank you

Comment: For anyone considering using this: note that it's important `block` is declared as **`[u16; 128]`** and not `[u8; 256]`, since if it is not properly aligned, `slice::from_raw_parts_mut` will invoke UB.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
for chunk in block.chunks_exact_mut(2) {
    chunk.copy_from_slice(&color.to_be_bytes());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.